# Passing information previously retrieved to templateProvider in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm using AngularJS 1.3 and UI-Router. I have an state in which i have a resolve and a templateProvider.

What i'm trying to accomplish is that the information retrieved from database in the resolve can be used by the templateProvider. Right now, I have to get the information twice, once from resolve and another from templateProvider, and that's annoying.

The code:

```
        .state('articleurl', {
          url: '/:articleUrl',
          resolve: {
            article: function ($http, $stateParams, $location) {

              return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/articles/' + $stateParams.articleUrl
              })
              .then(function (article) {

                  return article;

              }, function (error) {

                $location.path('/404');

              });
            },
            loggedin: checkLoggedin
          },
          templateProvider: ['$templateFactory', '$stateParams', '$http', function ($templateFactory, $stateParams, $http) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/articles/' + $stateParams.articleUrl
              }).then(function(article) {

                if ( article.data.template )
                  return $templateFactory.fromUrl('articles/views/templates/' + article.data.template + '.html');
                else
                  return $templateFactory.fromUrl('articles/views/templates/news.html');
            });
          }],
          controller: 'ArticlesViewController'
        })
```

As you can see, according to article's kind i load a different template in the templateProvider. Besides, i use the article's information in the controller which has been previously got in the state's resolve.

Is there any way to use in the templateProvider the information previously fetched in the resolve avoiding this way another call to database?

Right now, it is doing 2 calls to database per connection...

Thanks!

Comment: could use `ng-include` as template, pass `src` to it from controller

Comment: I was trying to avoid that approach in order to load the template directly from state, but likely it is the approach i will have to use if i cannot solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.factory('article', function ($cacheFactory){
  var articleCache = $cacheFactory('article'); 

  return function (url) {
    return articleCache.get(url) || articleCache.put(url, $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/articles/' + url
      })
    );
  };
});
```

Use it as `article($stateParams.articleUrl).then(...)` in both places, that will keep the things DRY. You may get better control over the cache (e.g. expiration) by replacing `$cacheFactory` with [`angular-cache`](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache).

`$http` [own caching](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching) may be successfully used as well instead of explicit caching:

> If there are multiple GET requests for the same URL that should be
>   cached using the same cache, but the cache is not populated yet, only
>   one request to the server will be made and the remaining requests will
>   be fulfilled using the response from the first request.

Comment: Oh yes, this worked like a charm. Right now it only makes 1 request to database =) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can inject directly the resolved variables, so you could inject `article` in `templateProvider`:

```
   .state('articleurl', {
      url: '/:articleUrl',
      resolve: {
        article: function ($http, $stateParams, $location) {

          return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/articles/' + $stateParams.articleUrl
          })
          .then(function (article) {

              return article;

          }, function (error) {

            $location.path('/404');

          });
        },
        loggedin: checkLoggedin
      },
      templateProvider: ['$templateFactory', '$stateParams', '$http', 'article', function ($templateFactory, $stateParams, $http, article) {
        // Now here you can use article without the need to re-call it
      }],
      controller: 'ArticlesViewController'
    })
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm trying injecting it but it didn't just work... :(